# net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) error in codeigniter when using store locator

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and i am facing some issue. I have created a store locator by using core php.It's working perfectly.But i want to embed the code in codeigniter.I copied the files and when i try to run it's not displaying and showing following errors in console.

**GET http://xxx/application/views/webpages/storeLocator/storelocator.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)**

**GET http://xxx/application/views/webpages/libs/handlebars.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)**

**For your reference: i have taken the code from https://www.softaox.info/jquery-store-locator-google-map-with-country-state-city-dropdown/**

I added the following script path in header.php

````
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>application/views/webpages/libs/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url();?>application/views/webpages/storeLocator/storelocator.js"></script>```

NB:base_url is correct, because it's working for others.Anyone please help me . I tried different things last couple of days.
````

Comment: Might be permissions on that file, try and change the chmod and check chown too.

Comment: No not working.Is there any way to redirect it to act like normal php codes?(like third party) @marcogmonteiro

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your javascript inside your views folder. The views folder should only have your view files.

For assets like images, css and javascript you should create a folder in your root directory like public with the following structure:

```
application
system
public 
   - css
   - js 
   - img
```

Then in your views you load your javascript files with base url like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('public/js/libs/handlebars.min.js') ?>"></script>
```

All your files inside your application folder shouldn't be directly accessible. You only access your index.php outside said folder and let it do its magic.

Public files should be outside the application and system folders. Always.